# Parse Platform and Xamarin - how do I check if Client is initialized?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, parse-platform

I am using the Parse Platform in Visual Studio Mac on a Xamarin.Forms project, and I want to test if the ParseClient has been initialized.

I've tried this:

```
        var installation = ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation == null;
        Debug.WriteLine("installation exists: " + installation);
```

But that doesn't even print anything out at all, for some reason; it doesn't even give me an error, it appears to just ignore the code.

I've also tried this:

```
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery([arbitrary object]);
        ParseObject dispatchObjectReturned = await query.GetAsync([arbitrary ObjectId]);
        address = dispatchObjectReturned.Get<string>([arbitrary object property]);
        Debug.WriteLine("TestConnection returned address: " + address);
```

...which works, but has many obvious shortcomings, not least that it relies on pre-existing knowledge of objects names and Ids and properties.

How do I check if the Client is initialized?

Comment: There is not really a way to check if the client is initialized since in the initialization it only stores the keys and server url that you sent (it does not attempt to do any kind of connection at that moment). So, just call the initialize method and you can consider it is already initialized.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo what I've been doing in lieu of a direct test is creating, saving, and destroying a ParseObject to see if it throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

Self-answering:

I've been told that there's no direct way to do this.

So what I've been doing in lieu of a direct test is creating, saving, and destroying a ParseObject to see if it throws an error.

This is my code for that:

```
    public async Task<bool> ActiveConnectionStatus()
    {
        try
        {
            var testObject = new ParseObject("Test");
            await testObject.SaveAsync();
            await testObject.DeleteAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ParseAccess: ActiveConnectionStatus(): CONNECTION STATUS FAIL: " + e);
            return false;
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("ParseAccess: ActiveConnectionStatus(): success");
        return true;
    }
```